# I am not able to call method from another file to main project file to run my test case

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2019

I opened pre-existing excel file and delete it. But it is not getting deleted.
How can I do that?

Comment: It clearly says you must provide 1 parameter to `exceldownload` method. You are calling it as `a.exceldownload();` but method expect one argument `List<string> lst`.

Comment: As the error message says: The parameter `lst` is missing in your test code.

Comment: Actually i am not getting what should I give as a Parameter.

Comment: you need to reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in your test project, have you actually stepped through your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you cannot call a method that you have declared with one string List parameter if you don't give it that parameter.

```
public void exceldownload(List<string> lst)
```

I'm not sure if I understand well all your code, but You can fix this in two ways:

1. First you can give the list parameter to the exceldownload function, like that:

   ```
   public void Excel()
   {
       Program a = new Program();
       a.exceldownload(new List<string>()); //or you can add in the list that you want to contain
   }
   ```
2. you can change the definition of the exceldownload function in order to accept also no parameters by using optional parameter:

   ```
   public void exceldownload(List<string> lst = null)
   {
       if(lst == null) {
           //TODO: manage this null as it should be
       }
       string str;
       int rw = 0;
       int cl = 0;
   ```

Hope this will help you

Comment: In case you will not send a parameter or in case you will send null as parameter this line will crash: `if (!lst[i - 1].Equals(str))`.
To avoid that you should manage this null, but this depends by the needs of your app. Maybe you should throw an error, maybe you should stop processing this null list, etc